# Parse POST HTTP response using Python

Tags: python, parsing, httprequest, httpresponse

i want to parse a POST HTTP response using python.

My response looks like:

```
{
  "Result": 0,
  "ResponseStatus": {
    "ErrorCode": null,
    "Message": null,
    "StackTrace": null,
    "Errors": null
  },
  "SessionId": "68ebcd6f-0aef-420d-a12b-c953f8df8ed1",
  "ResponseHeader": {
    "Succeeded": true,
    "Errors": []
  }
}
```

I want to parse the - "SessionID" to a 2nd http request. 
How can i achieve it? Thanks !

Comment: use the json module.

Comment: Please add the code you use to retrieve that, so we can assist based on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json 
response = '{"Result": 0, "ResponseStatus": { "ErrorCode": null,"Message": null, "StackTrace": null, "Errors": null },"SessionId": "68ebcd6f-0aef-420d-a12b-c953f8df8ed1", "ResponseHeader": { "Succeeded": true, "Errors": [] } }'
json_response = json.loads(response)
print json_response['SessionId']
```

I guess you are using urllib, I recommend using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Comment: Thanks! i'm new in python. i will appreciate if you will help me to write 2 http requests that the 2nd request is based on the SessionId from the 1st request